# having an issue with a sticky footer on my beer site

Tags: css, sticky-footer

My upcoming site, http://beerwhich.com/tester/loggedIn.html is using a sticky footer that is explained here: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

For some reason at the bottom there is a small gap, so the big beer bottle does not bleed off the footer edge as it should.

Any idea why? I'm using .container as my wrapper, which has a negative margin that is equal to the height of .footer

Comment: That is not a sticky footer. It doesn't _stick_ to the bottom of the browser window, independent of the scroll position.

Comment: @Sean: Check in Firefox 5 using Web Developer Toolbar. Select CSS, Disable Styles, Browser Default Styles. When you disable that, it works.

Comment: Should this be there after the footer <img width="62" height="25" title="Information about the fonts used on this site" class="typekit-badge" id="typekit-badge-ayi0hoq" style="left: 1198px; top: 2461px; width: 65px; height: 25px; right: auto; bottom: auto; text-indent: 0px; overflow: visible; ="http://use.typekit.com/badges/default.gif"/>

Comment: @Jawad, that's really weird-the typekit thing is supposed to be there-it's their logo for when we go live. I removed it in firebug and that does not seem to do it :(

Comment: @Sean: In FF5 on Windows 7, if I remove html, body {height: 100%;} and in style.css line 36, change body, textarea {line-height: 18px;} to line-height: 8px;}, it solves the problem. When viewed with Firebbug and with html,body height set to 100%, they do not "wrap" around all the elements in the page. - http://i56.tinypic.com/10xsks9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`#loggedIn .footer, .push` (line 889), instead of `height:195px  !important` -

`height:200px !important`.
A difference of 5px. that's all.

Comment: I'd just add a `margin-bottom` to `.push`.

Comment: @Blender Hey, they are all being declared on the same line, by changing the code there you are changing it here too :).

Comment: But that would create a `10px` difference, as the height changes by `5px` twice.

Comment: Right. If he wants to declare the height of `.footer` ** separately** , then he'll need to make the `height:205px`, but since changing it right now changes `.push` **and** `.footer`, he needs to change it to `200px` only.

Comment: I think fixing the sticky footer (which isn't sticky at all) would be a good addition to your answer. Delete the content `<div>`s with Firebug or Chrome's Inspector and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Blender let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1309/discussion-between-eric-and-blender)

Comment: what style is messed up Eric?

Comment: Why do u even have that .push div? Now am thinking maybe you need it for old browsers. But the fact that it's needed is messed up, although it's not your fault. (I hate IE)

Comment: What do you mean not working?  What browser are u using, what changes did u make to the code

Comment: Hey Eric, I'm using firefox and I changed #loggedIn .footer, .push from 195px to 200px

Comment: OK, change `.push` only. Make a separate declaration for it, and make it 200, leave the rest as it was(195px). if it still doesn't work, change `.push` to 205px.

Comment: thanks for trying Eric! I left it up so you can see..it's still not doing  the trick it just keeps bumping it down but leaving the gap if you scroll to see it. http://beerwhich.com/tester/loggedIn.html

Comment: no, keep the 195 of .footer and #loggedin, just change the `.push` to 5px more than `.footer`.                                                      For the record, if I were you, I will make the footer narrower, and set that beer bottle as a CSS `background-image`. If the above doesn't work, you should try this approach. Otherwise am out of ideas...